# Parsing html and decoding symbols with Dart

Tags: html, parsing, dart, decoding, utf

I try parsing html from url. Charset this page is "windows-1251", and output content from my method coded is utf.

I try use http and html packages like this:

```
getContentFrom(String uri, {List selectors}) async {
    var htmlForParse, content, html;

    Map headers = {'Content-type':'text/html', 'charset':'windows-1251'};

    htmlForParse = await http.read(uri, headers: headers);

    html = parse(htmlForParse, encoding:'utf-8');
}
```

http.read return:

```
'<a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Ðîáîò Parrot Jumping Sumo (÷åðíûé)"/></a>'
```

It's only when it try get from not utf charset page.

Dart code like that: https://github.com/Rasarts/mini.parser/blob/master/lib/parser.dart

And finally output like so "Parrot Jumping Sumo (÷åðíûé)", but i expected "Parrot Jumping Sumo (черный)"

What can i do for fix that ÷åðíûé ?

Comment: It may help if you add the text as it is supposed to appear. Does the text appear correct (in Cyrillic characters) *before* attempting to re-parse it?

Comment: http.read return: '<a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Ðîáîò Parrot Jumping Sumo (÷åðíûé)"/></a>'. It's only when it try get from not utf charset page. [Dart code like that](https://github.com/Rasarts/mini.parser/blob/master/lib/parser.dart)

I just use print() function for see result.

Comment: Please use [edit] to add information to your post; do not use comments for that. Also, what it is *supposed* to return? As it is, you seem to get exactly what the inout is.

Comment: "÷åðíûé" must be 'черный', on the page it's displayed correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a small function for this purpose: https://github.com/Rasarts/mini.parser/blob/master/lib/cp1251.dart